# Showing that $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = |\operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Show that the cardinality of a power set of natural numbers is exactly equal to the map of a set of natural numbers to another, which is $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = |\operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{N})|$.

I cannot find anything to start with other than knowing there is an injective map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Any suggestions for the tags? Tks

Comment: Can you define an injective map from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\operatorname{Maps}(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N})$ ? That's already something.

Answer (score 2):

By Cantor-Bernstein, it's enough to find (1) an injection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ into $Maps(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N})$, and (2) an injection from $Maps(\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N})$ into $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Towards (1): Suppose I have a set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. This can be viewed as a map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{Yes, No\}$ - you ask "is $n\in X$?" and I output "Yes" or "No" accordingly. Does this help?

Towards (2): This one's a bit harder, but: a function $F$ is completely defined by its *graph*, the set $\{(a, b): F(a)=b\}$. So . . .

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little later but I got a homework about that recently.

Consider $f(i,j)=2^{i}(2j+1)-1$, notice that it is bijective, then as you got a bijection equinumerosity is proved automatically.